# Get og:image from url using JSoup

Tags: coldfusion, jsoup

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. I am tring to get the og:image url using JSOUP and Coldfusion.

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="http://www.bbc.com/culture/story/20150304-is-house-of-cards-worth-watching" result="theresult">


<cfscript>
    // Create the jsoup object
    Jsoup = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup");

    // HTML string
    html = "#theresult.filecontent#";
    // Parse the string
    document = Jsoup.parse(html);
    // Extract content
    title = document.title();
    metaOgImage  = document.select("meta[property=og:image]").first();

    writeOutput("
        <div>Title: #title#</div>       
        <div>Meta: #metaOgImage#</div>
    ");
</cfscript>
```

Comment: What does it return? I don't know the select syntax of Jsoup, but try `'meta[property="og:image"]'` maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `metaOgImage  = document.select("meta[property=og:image]").first();`

The returns an [Element](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html) representing the `<meta>` tag. To display only the "content" attribute (which is where that page stores the url), try:

```
<div>Meta: #metaOgImage.attr("content")#</div>
```

Keep in mind `metaOgImage` could be null, if it wasn't found, so be sure to add handling for that in the CF code.

Comment: ..  and obviously add handling to verify the cfhttp call returned 200, or the subsequent JSoup call may throw an error.